# Pygame player not moving

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game that involves a player moving left and right. However, in my code below, the player can' be moved. Can anyone tell me why the player1 sprite is not moving? It appears on the game screen but the player doesn't move on left or right when I press the movement keys.

Code:

```py
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

game_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Whiskey Goggles")

bg = pygame.image.load("bg.png")
bg_image = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (600, 600))

class Player:

    def __init__(self, image_path, width, height, x, y):

        self.image_path = image_path
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        player = pygame.image.load(image_path)
        self.player_main = pygame.transform.scale(player, (width,height))

    def draw(self, background):

        background.blit(self.player_main, (self.x, self.y))

#Main game

game_on = True
while game_on:

    clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
    clock.tick(60)

    direction = 0

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_on = False
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                direction = 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                direction = -1
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                direction = 0

    game_screen.fill((0,0,0))
    game_screen.blit(bg_image, (0,0))

    player1 = Player("glass.png", 70, 70, 25, 500)
    player1.draw(game_screen)

    if direction > 0:
        player1.x = player1.x + 10
    elif direction < 0:
        player1.x = player1.x - 10

    pygame.display.update()

quit()
```

Comment: The base class (which eventually all classes inherit from) for all classes in python is `object`, so creating a class called `Object` is probably not the best choice. That is not your problem, just an observation.

Comment: As GlennMackintosh said; use descriptive names. If the class is creating a player, then name the class `Player`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new player every loop at the same position (and resetting the `direction`). Create it outside of the loop.

```
game_on = True
player1 = Object("glass.png", 70, 70, 25, 500)  # Create the player here instead.
direction = 0  # The same with direction.
while game_on:

    clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
    clock.tick(60)

    # direction = 0 Don't reset the direction every loop.

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_on = False
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                direction = 1
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                direction = -1
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                direction = 0

    game_screen.fill((0,0,0))
    game_screen.blit(bg_image, (0,0))

    # player1 = Object("glass.png", 70, 70, 25, 500)  # Don't do this.
    player1.draw(game_screen)

    if direction > 0:
        player1.x = player1.x + 10
    elif direction < 0:
        player1.x = player1.x - 10

       
    pygame.display.update()
```